# Random simple walk recurrence, walker leaves an interval

Tags: probability, random-walk

My question concerns an excercise given by my probability theory teacher.

Consider a simple random walk, i.e., we have iid sequence $U_1, U_2,\dots$ with $\mathbb P(U_i=-1)=\mathbb P(U_i=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Define $X_0=0$ and for $n\geq 0$: $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^nU_i$.

Define for $k>0$,
 $q_k=\mathbb P$(the walker leaves the interval $(-1,k)$ in position $k$)

Show that $q_k=\frac{1}{2}((1-q_{k-1})q_k+q_{k-1}) $.

I think I have an answer: if the walker goes to 1 (probability $\frac{1}{2}$) and we condition on this position we see that he has probability $q_{k-1}$ to leave the interval $(0,k)$ in position $k$, and he has probability $1-q_{k-1}$ to not do this and go back to zero. Here he essentially starts over, and he has probability $q_k$ to leave the interval $(-1,k)$ in position $k$.

However, how do I make this more formal instead of mere telling why this is so?

Comment: Note that $q_k=P_0(X_{T_k}=k)$ where $T_k=\inf\{n\mid X_n\in\{-1,k\}\}$. If $X_{T_{k-1}}=-1$ then $X_{T_k}=-1$ hence $q_k=P_0(X_{T_k}=k,X_{T_{k-1}}=k-1)$, that is, $q_k=q_{k-1}P_0(X_{T_k}=k\mid X_{T_{k-1}}=k-1)$. Finally,$P_0(X_{T_k}=k\mid X_{T_{k-1}}=k-1)=P_{k-1}(X_{T_k}=k)$ and by the invariance of the process by the symmetry $x\to k-1-x$, $P_{k-1}(X_{T_k}=k)=P_0(X_{T_k}=-1)=1-q_k$.